# Create a tensor from another with a condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor like this

```
...
0
0
2
0
1
0
3
1
0
0
0
0
2
3
...
```

and I must find a way to create a tensor of the same shape but with only 0 and 1. The one must be in the same position as a specific number. Here an example

```
# for number 2
...
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
...
```

Is there a built-in function that can do that? I can't find anything online and in the documentation.

Then I have to multiply this tensor by a list of numbers like this

```
l = [..., 1.3, 4.3, ...]
```

to obtain this

```
...
0
0
1.3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
4.3
0
...
```

Is there a way to obtain this result?

**edit**

I'm having trouble in applying this method in my case. I explain it. My tensor in which to take the indices is like this

```
points = tf.constant([[[0], [1], [0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [2], [0], [1]],
                      [[1], [2], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [2], [0], [2]],
                      [[0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [0], [1], [2], [0], [1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
# shape=(3, 10, 1)
```

I have to take the indices only of the first row so I take them in this way

```
idx = tf.cast(tf.where(tf.equal(tf.slice(points, [0, 0, 0], [1, 10, 1]), tf.constant([2], dtype=tf.float32))), dtype=tf.int32)
# shape=(3, 3)
idx = tf.expand_dims(idx, 0)
# shape=(1, 3, 3)
```

The values to feed are inside a list called `vectors` and I transformed them to have the same shape like this

```
to_feed = np.expand_dims(np.array(vectors), 0)
# shape=(1, 3, 3)
```

and then I apply the method in this way

```
res = tf.scatter_nd(idx, to_feed, tf.shape(tf.slice(points, [0, 0, 0], [1, 10, 3])))
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: The inner 0 dimensions of output.shape=[?,?,?] must match the inner 1 dimensions of updates.shape=[1,3,3]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for 'ScatterNd' (op: 'ScatterNd') with input shapes: [1,3,3], [1,3,3], [3].
```

What I need at the end is a tensor like this

```
to_feed = [[[10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], [12, 12, 12]]] # shape=(1, 3, 3)
res = [[[0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10], [0, 0, 0], [11, 11, 11], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [12, 12, 12], [0, 0, 0]]] # shape=(1, 10, 3)
```

(The `[0, 0, 0]` are put randomly just to have an idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compare with [`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) and then convert the boolean result to a number with [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast):

```
import tensorflow as tf

vector = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
result = tf.cast(tf.equal(vector, num), tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={vector: [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0], num: 2}))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
```

---

EDIT:

The above solves the simpler first question, but I think what you need to solve your problem is something like the following, using [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) and [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

vector = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
idx = tf.where(tf.equal(vector, num))
result = tf.scatter_nd(idx, values, tf.cast(tf.shape(vector), idx.dtype))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={vector: [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0],
                                      num: 2,
                                      values: [3, 4.4, 2, 2.2]}))
```

Output:

```
[0.  3.  0.  4.4 0.  2.  2.2 0. ]
```

---

EDIT:

About your latest example, I have put together a snippet for what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
import tensorflow as tf

points = tf.constant([[[0], [1], [0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [2], [0], [1]],
                      [[1], [2], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [2], [0], [2]],
                      [[0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [0], [1], [2], [0], [1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
vectors = tf.constant([[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 21]], dtype=tf.float32)

points_row = points[:1]
idx = tf.where(tf.equal(points_row, 2))
idx = tf.cast(idx, tf.int32)
res_shape = tf.concat([tf.shape(points_row), [tf.shape(vectors)[1]]], axis=0)
res = tf.scatter_nd(idx, vectors, res_shape)
res = tf.squeeze(res, 2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [10. 11. 12.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [20. 21. 22.]
  [30. 31. 21.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! and for the second part? Have you an idea?

Comment: @User Ah wait I didn't read that right. You should be able to just multiply one tensor with another with the `*` operator (as long as they have compatible dimensions). Just note you will probably have to cast the result so data types match (for example, if your second tensor is of type `tf.float32`, then you would `tf.cast` to that instead of `tf.int32`).

Comment: Yes I thought about multiplying it but the problem is that the tensor has a shape of for example [200, 1] and the values are inside a list which could have a length of for example 40, so I can't use a multiplication between tensors. The first element of the list must be multiplied with the first one in the tensor and so on.

Comment: So in your example, out of those `[200, 1]` values, you would only be interested in the first 40, and those would be multiplied by the 0 or 1 values in the other vector?

Comment: No in 200 elements I have N elements for example 40 that are 1 and each element of the list of values must be multiplied with these ones. For example, the list has 4 values `list = [3, 4.4, 2, 2.2]` and this means that inside the tensor I have only 4 ones and the first one must be 3, the second 4.4 and so on. But the ones are random inside the tensor not in the head or in the tail.

Comment: @User I think I understand what you mean, I have updated the answer with another snippet doing that.

Comment: can you help me with what I added in the edit part of my question?

Comment: @User I added another update, although I am not sure it does what you actually want.

Comment: What I want to do is to take the indices from the `points` and use them to insert my values in another tensor with the shape of `[1, 10, 3]`, so in my example inside the `points` I have the number `0, 1, 2`, I want to take the indices of the number `2` and use them to put my values in a tensor of the same shape of `points` but with 3 coordinates as the third dimension

Comment: @User Updated again, still not sure if that's it. To be honest, these are all different (and increasingly complex) questions, in the future please consider either posting a new question for each or asking the full question in the first place.